# Watershed - local minima in greyscale image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, watershed

I have a set of greyscale images where I need to locate the local minima. I'm writing my code in Matlab and I'm looking for suggestions on how to structure the algorithm: do I need to calculate the gradient or can I just use the `watershed` function?

This is the code I used to do a first analysis (images below):

```
IM_c = imcomplement(IM);
L = watershed(IM_c);
Lrgb = label2rgb(L);
figure; hold on;
subplot(3,1,1); imshow(IM_c); hold on;
subplot(3,1,2); imshow(Lrgb);hold on;
subplot(3,1,3); imshow(imfuse(IM_c,Lrgb));
```

[image]

Intuitively, I expect to find regional minima in the pixels pointed by arrows:
[image]

Comment: What is the question?Is this what you wanted? If not, what *do* you want?

Comment: The question is: how can I avoid oversampling and efficiently find regional minima?

Comment: In a very intuitive way, my final aim is to detect the spots pointed by arrow in the figure https://www.evernote.com/shard/s73/sh/16cb0a69-c09a-4d56-bfea-a5211431f5dd/2a50cc0218447011e01d226c82b9624a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the solution would be to use a gradient image, following the algorithm described in [this](http://www.hindawi.com/journals/ddns/2008/384346/) paper. The procedure is quite complicated, so instead I

1. Cleaned the image using `imerode` and `imdilate`;
2. Made a binarized version (`IM_bin`) of the image and used it as a filter, so that 
   if IM_bin(x,y) > 0
       IM_clean(x,y) = IM(x,y);
   else
       IM_clean(x,y) = 0;
3. Used `imerode` again;
4. Looked for regional maxima using `imregionalmax`.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that the image is extremely noisy. You should blur it so that you remove the local noise.
For example, you can use Gaussian or box blur or morphological smoothing, e.g. with a close operation.

I'm not sure watershed is the right tool. Morphological erode assigns the local minima in a defined neighborhood of each pixel. Subtract the *original* image from the *eroded* image and threshold at -1. The remaining non-zero pixels, are the local minima.

Comment: Hi, I would prefer not to blur the image so to preserve all information. Is there a way to consider only composed by at least `n` pixels when using `watershed`?

Comment: @albus_c, if you preserve all the information, the number of local minima simply is that large. If you only want those minima pointed out, you have to remove the others, which inevitably means getting rid of information. Luckily, that information can be qualified as "noise".

Answer (score 2):

As Adi Shavit mentioned, the image is very noisy. This leads to over-segmentation when using the watershed on the image directly (since there are many extrema across the image).

You do need to perform some kind of preprocessing to smooth the image. If you don't want to use blurring, you can try morphological reconstruction (`imreconstruct`) before finding the extrema.

```
% if img is your original grayscale image

wSize = 6;
se = strel('disk', wSize);

% opening by reconstruction - to remove specks in the dark background
imgEroded = imerode(img, se);
imgRecon = imreconstruct(imgEroded, img);

imgReconComp = imcomplement(imgRecon);

% opening by reconstruction - to homogenize the pixels in the foreground(clouds)
imgEroded2 = imerode(imgReconComp, se);
imgRecon2 = imreconstruct(imgEroded2, imgReconComp);

minima = imregionalmin(imgRecon2);
```

The minima overlaid on the original image looks like this -

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPHh0.png]

You can experiment with the size/shape of the structuring element to see if you get any better results.

You can also use the extrema as seeds to perform watershed segmentation on the gradient image, but this will likely not produce a meaningful result (it doesn't look like you are trying to perform segmentation anyway).